# Show Last month progress of user on base of actions on website django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have designed my database like this

```
user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
signup = models.FloatField(default=10)
signup_from_user_link = models.FloatField(default=0)
post_review = models.FloatField(default=0)
total = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I am calculating overall progress of user by adding all these values . But Now I have to make a change and  I want to show progress of last month. Like in last month how much user added in every filed . What will be easiest way to get value of  last month addition into these filed.

Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: What do the fields represent and what does the user "add" to them? You will probably need a separate model that contains each change with a datetime and then use an annotation/aggregation to calculate the last month

Comment: @IainShelvington  I am using just id of user to show latter progress of user on dashboard . for now its showing for rating of all time .   How I can keep record of all these fields changes ? you have any example for this logic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a model that stores the time of creation and a "value" for an event (like submitting a review), every time a user performs the action you create an instance of this model

```
class Action(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='actions')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

You can then use aggregation to sum all the values for the event in the last month for a user with this query

```
total_for_last_month = user.actions.filter(
    timestamp__gt=datetime.datetime.now() - dateutil.relativedelta(months=1)
).aggregate(
    total=Sum('value')
)['total']
```

You would probably want to rename the model as "Review" or something and might want to add more fields

If you wish to calculate the total for a queryset of profiles then you can annotate each one

```
users = Profile.objects.filter(
    actions__timestamp__gt=datetime.datetime.now() - dateutil.relativedelta(months=1)
).annotate(
    total=Sum('actions__value')
)
```

Comment: I want to keep record like  'review'  or 'dish addition '  etc  . then I have to save name of action and value as well ? Am i right ?  So when i will get  I will check what thing was added by user in previous month

Comment: and if actions are too many like 8 , 9 then still its good way to storing all actions in same way ?  And how to get all actions name aswell ?

Comment: You can create a model for each action, in your case I think "Review", then you create and aggregate using this model instead of adding the name of the action. You could also create a generic "Action" model that has name if you want to have multiple actions, you would just need to filter on that name in your query

Comment: This has a slight drawback that the "value" column in this example would always be a float

Comment: okay . Till now I got that I need to create 8 new models for that . and to get data from every model I need to do that query for 8 times for every one ?  btw I need float value :D

Comment: And thank you so so much for help . last thing  aggregation query to get sum will be in view.py ?

Comment: Yes, or you could add a property to the `Profile` model

Comment: how can i add in profile ? I didnt get this ? 8 fields ?

Comment: 8 properties, maybe leave it in the view for now until you need to get the total in multiple views

Comment: Hi , I am trying this today. by mean of your user  is    request.user ???? which is logged in ?