# Get data of table between 2 dates django python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a table in model like this

```
class ReviewMonthly(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ReviewMonthly')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

i want to get data of  value between two dates like I have saved data and the other  is I am getting like `datetime.datetime.now()`

> Update

when I tried to run following in my view.py

```
total_for_last_month =request.user.profile.ReviewMonthly (
        timestamp__gt=datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)
    ).aggregate(
        total=Sum('value')
    )['total']
```

I got this error

**__call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timestamp__gt'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
ReviewMonthly.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(first_datetime, timezone.now()))
```

Here *`first_datetime`* is a `datetime` object that contains the first timestamp.

If you want to use a check on the dates instead, you can use:

```
ReviewMonthly.objects.filter(
    timestamp__date__range=(first_datetime.date(), timezone.now().date())
)
```

As for the other queryset, you forgot to call `.filter(...)`:

```
total_for_last_month =request.user.profile.ReviewMonthly.filter(
    timestamp__gt=datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)
).aggregate(
    total=Sum('value')
)['total']
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply ,   I want to do something like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648240/show-last-month-progress-of-user-on-base-of-actions-on-website-django/57648895?noredirect=1#comment101748604_57648895        but I am getting errors

Comment: @gamer: what error do you get? Can you edit your question and post the error(s)?

Comment: Done . kindly have a look

Comment: @gamer: you forgot a `.filter(..)`

Comment: Thanks Willem <3 . thank you so much.And one more thing I need  suggestion about design of this scenarios  is it good to save progress of a  person like this ?. And any good book and resourse for advance topics like this. I am new in programming and python . thanks in advance

Comment: @gamer: this *can* be a good modeling, yes. Actually the Django documentation and the tutorial are actually imho of quite good quality :)

Comment: Hi Willem I am trying to get data of last 7 days using this   Restaurant.objects.filter(timestamp__gt=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7))  but its returning whole data table created 2 days ago. I need record of last 7 days . Can you help me about where I am wrong ?

Comment: @gamer: but if you want the last seven days, then that includes the data of two days ago, right?

Comment: yes . I got that I should use  __lt   instead of __gt. am I right ?

Comment: @gamer: by using `__lt`, you will retrieve all data older than seven days ago. If you want to retrieve all data exactly seven days ago, you can use `timestamp__date=(datetime.now()-timedelta(days=7)).date()`

Comment: thanks for your help <3 you save me every time bro. <3.